# TYPO3/Chrome: Text overflow when printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, typo3, typo3-10.x

I have the following problem:

In Chrome, a text overflow occurs when I try to print a section.
I have already created a print.css with all possible styles, which is also properly integrated and called. But unfortunately the overflow does not go away. Can someone help me or does anyone have an idea of ​​what it could be?

TYPO3 v10.4
Chrome v102.0.5005.61

[image: printpreview]

Comment: This should be a CSS issue, not a TYPO3 issue. Anyway, as long as you don't share some snippet and screenshot, no one can help you.

Comment: According to the screenshot, probably this is no text-overflow as the CSS term overflow indicates, but rather a container (e.g. a <div>) which is just too big. Remember (depending on box model) that a 100% width + padding + margin is more than fits, so decrease the width of the container.

Comment: Here you find a description [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a chrome error. But thank you for your support https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1330475&sort=type&q=Print&can=2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).